# Change image contrast via CSS in Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm currently making a webpage that allows a user to dynamically modify an image's contrast value in Chrome using "-webkit-filter: contrast".  Unfortunately because neither Mozilla Firefox nor Internet Explorer use the WebKit engine (Gecko and Trident respectively), they don't support the filter styles that I'm currently using for image processing/manipulation.  Due to the nature of the images I am unable to use a JavaScript image processing library to handle this, hence why I need to use CSS instead.  Are there any equivalent styles used by Mozilla Firefox and/or Internet Explorer that would allow me to change an image's contrast value?  Thanks a bunch guys.

Short version

- need to change image contrast with CSS
- can't use JavaScript library
- currently using "-webkit-filter: contrast" for Chrome, need something similar for IE and Firefox

Comment: Might be more trouble than it's worth, but you could perhaps embed the image within an SVG graphic and then use SVG filters. IIRC, modern browsers have pretty good support for SVG filters.

Comment: If you drop the prefix (`filter: contrast();`), does that work for at least firefox?

Comment: @Chad: Not yet, though Mozilla is working on it

Comment: @Stephen Thomas: I'll look into embedding the images into an SVG, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no possibility to affect the content of an image in Firefox or Internet Explorer.